# Array to String conversion error while trying to do a single file upload in Laraver using AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, file-upload, laravel-8, jquery-file-upload

I'm having form which submits one file and certain texts through AJAX, only problem is with the file upload through AJAX. The form dats is being submitted through FormData instance but getting an Array to String conversion error while trying to save the file.
I'm attaching the scripts below.

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'contact_number' => 'required|numeric',
            'email' => 'required', 
            'total_exp' => 'required|numeric',
            'skillsets' => 'required',
            'current_organization' => '',
            'remarks' => '',
            'file_name' => 'required|max:2048'
        ],
        [   
            'name' => 'This field is mandatory',
            'contact_number' => 'This field is mandatory',
            'email' => 'This field is mandatory', 
            'total_exp' => 'This field is mandatory',
            'skillsets' => 'This field is mandatory',
            'total_exp.numeric' => 'Only numberic values allowed',
            'contact_number.numeric' => 'Only numberic values allowed'
        ]);

        //try{
        $career = CareerForm::updateOrCreate([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'contact_number'=>$request->contact_number,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'total_exp'=>$request->total_exp,
            'skillsets'=>$request->skillsets,
            'current_organization'=>$request->current_organization,
            'remarks'=>$request->remarks,
            'file_name' => $request->file_name,
            ]);
        
        //if(request()->hasFile('file_name')){
        
        $file=$request->file('file_name');
        $fname = rand().'.'.$file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file('file_name')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('documents'),$fname);
        //$file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fname);
            //$request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);*/
        /*$file = $request->file('file_name')->store('public/documents');
        Storage::disk('local')->put($request->file($request->file)->getClientOriginalName(), 'Contents');*/
        //}catch(Exception $e1){echo $e1;}
        return response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            
        ]);
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h2>Career Form using AJAX</h2>
<form class="form-signin" id="form_todo"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Career Form</h1>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Name</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('name')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Contact Number</label>
  <input name="contact_number" type="" id="c_n" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('contact_number')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Email</label>
  <input name="email" type="text" id="eml" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('email')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Total Experience</label>
  <input name="total_exp" type="" id="exp" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Experience" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('total_experience')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Skillsets</label>
  <input name="skillsets" type="text" id="skl" class="form-control" placeholder="Skillsets" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('skillsets')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Curent Organization</label>
  <input name="current_organization" type="text" id="c_o" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Organizations (Optional)" autofocus="">
  @error('current_organization')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Remarks</label>
  <input name="remarks" type="text" id="rem" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks (Optional)" autofocus="">
  @error('remarks')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror

  
  <input type="file" id="file_id" name="file_name[]" class="form-control">
  <!--<button type="button" id="btnFile" class="btn btn-primary">Submit File</button>-->
  
  <button class="btn  btn-primary btn-block" id="career_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>


<p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">Done by Debajyoti Das</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }

    });
  });
    $("#form_todo").on('submit',function(e) {
    //$("#career_btn").click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      //var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      //var files = $("#file_id")[0].files;
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      //formData.append('file_id',files[0]);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "career/store",
        data: formData,
        datatype: 'JSON',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
        }
      });
    });
  
</script>

@endsection
```

JSON error message: Array to string conversion
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On your server You have accepted an array of files.

```
$files=$request->file('file_name');
foreach ($files as file) {
        $fname = rand().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('documents'),$fname);

}
```

Comment: Did the following but same error. Attaching the code below.:
 $files=$request->file('file_name');
        foreach($files as $file){
        $fname = rand().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('documents'),$fname);}

Comment: I thing this is the right way to deal with an array.Check your code logic may You have a problem with local storage and check laravel.log file to get  the error exception.